# Is it possible to add authentication on the basis of single model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers


LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]

class Classname(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name

class Sectionname(models.Model):
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(Classname)
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name

class Teachername(models.Model):
    classname = models.ForeignKey(Classname, verbose_name='class Name')
    secname = models.ForeignKey(Sectionname, verbose_name='sectionname')
    teachname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='teacher Name')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.teachname

class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')

    def hours_conversion(self):
        tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.outtime) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.intime))
        hours, minutes = tdelta.seconds//3600, (tdelta.seconds//60)%60
    return '{0}hrs {1}mins'.format(hours, minutes)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Classname, Sectionname, Teachername, Attendancename


class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Classname
        fields = ('id', 'class_name',)

class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sectionname
        fields = ('id', 'class_name', 'section_name')

class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teachername
        fields = ('id', 'classname', 'secname', 'teachname')

class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendancename
        fields = ('id', 'teacher_name', 'date', 'intime', 'outtime')
```

I want to add owner field in my models to enforce DRF authentication system. Is it necessary to add `'owner'` field to all my models above?

I'm following a tutorial on django-rest-framework I have several models as above. Is it possible to make a single model for this authentication purpose and to set permissions in serializers file as per that model & to access all models on the basis of that single model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add owner field in my models to enforce DRF authentication system

You don't need the owner field to "enforce" the authentication.

How to enable and handle authentication in DRF is explained here in all details: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

The owner field is only interesting for certain permission cases.

If you look at the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#tutorial-4-authentication-permissions), you'll see that DRF already ships with permissions for common cases like `IsAuthenticated`, `IsAdmin` and many more. Depending on the state of a user (logged in / logged out) he or she might see certain resources or not.

However, if you want to set [object level permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions) you need the owner field (or something comparable).

How else can you tell if a certain user is really associated with a certain object?

For all this the default User model (from `django.contrib.auth`) should be completely sufficient and I see no need for any extra models assuming you use one of [the standard Authentication Backends](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) which set `request.user` to an instance of User.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpfull